# MVC: View with remote hosted layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

So, our client wants to embed our MVC applicaiton in their site. First solution on my mind - load our application in a iFrame on their site, and we are done.

Turns out what they want is a bit more complex (and imo stupid).
We must still host our application, but when a user comes to our site, it must look like their site with our content - our views, their layout - but they want to host the layout.

So every time a request is made, a page (layout) is retrieved from client's site, our rendered view is shoved into it and displayed back to the end user.

So the question is: is it possible to do what the client wants, because I can't wrap my head around how this should be done with MVC?

Any comments or suggestions?

Comment: I would step back and ask yourself and your client, what they REALLY NEED? and why they are asking it to be this horrible way. Probably they don't want your application, they want your content and then JSON and WebApi way is the best.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to simply expose your data to them and let them render it whichever way they want.  You could have your controllers simply spit out JSON for them and let them do with it as they please.  This all assumes there isn't any heavy lifting being done on the view, however.

Answer (score 1):

What they are asking for is really outside of what the MVC view engine does, but it still may be possible.  The view engine does not assemble a web page from various web resources the same way a web browser does.  A browser will load JS, CSS, and images based on what is specified in the html.  The view engine will load views, templates, and layouts based on what is inside a directory structure within the MVC application.  It is not designed to grab these files from another server.

However, I think you can get this work, although it will be riddled with security concerns.  You can create a symbolic link within your Views directory that links to a network share hosted by your client.  In this share will be the layout they want you to use.  Now, from your own views within the Views directory (not in the network share), you reference the layout:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/HostedNetworkShare/layout.cshtml";
}
```

Because of the security concerns, I **DO NOT** recommend this method, but I also see no reason why it couldn't work.  It will also require some cooperation from you client in hosting the network share.